# Remove nil in Clojure 2D-vector

Tags: clojure

What is the best way to remove the nils in a 2D-Vector in Clojure?

```
[[250 634]] [[450 598] [250 651]] [[450 615] [250 668]] [[450 632] [250 685]] [[450 649] [259 700]] [[450 666] [323 700]] [[450 683] [386 700]] [nil nil] [nil nil] [nil nil] [nil nil] [nil nil] [nil nil] [nil nil]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `remove` to remove elements out of a collection if they meet the criteria of a given predicate function. Now, you can use a `set` as a function, so you can use the set `#{[nil nil]}` to remove the undesired elements, like this:

```clj
user=> (def elems [[[250 634]] [[450 598] [250 651]] [[450 615] [250 668]] [[450 632] [250 685]] [[450 649] [259 700]] [[450 666] [323 700]] [[450 683] [386 700]] [nil nil] [nil nil] [nil nil] [nil nil] [nil nil] [nil nil] [nil nil]])
#'user/elems

user=> (remove #{[nil nil]} elems)
([[250 634]] [[450 598] [250 651]] [[450 615] [250 668]] [[450 632] [250 685]] [[450 649] [259 700]] [[450 666] [323 700]] [[450 683] [386 700]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(filter (fn [x] (every? not-nil x) your-vec)
```

Filters the vector by making sure that the sub-vector isn't just full of nils. If you want to filter out *any* vectors with nil use some instead of every?. If you want to keep the (potentially empty) sub-vectors then use filter instead of every?:

```
(filter (fn [x] (filter not-nil x) your-vec)
```

Comment: okay i understand but "not-nil" isn't working

Unable to resolve symbol: not-nil in this context

Comment: @droizenberg `(defn not-nil [x] (not (nil? x)))`

Comment: `(filter (fn [x] (not-any? nil? x)) your-vec)`  By the way, these functions are listed at https://clojure.github.io/clojure/

Comment: @BipedPhill thanks. Sometimes I just use the building blocks I can keep in my head rather than google for shorter ones, you must have a better memory than me!

Comment: `(remove (fn [x] (some nil? x)) your-vec)`

Answer (score 0):

`mapv` is a variant of `map` that returns a vector. In the same way, can define `removev`: a variant of `remove` that returns a vector:

```
(defn removev [pred v]
  (into [] (remove pred v)))
```

We can make a predicate that detects `[nil nil]` by wrapping it in a set: `#{[nil nil]}`.

By combining these, we have what we want:

```
(removev #{[nil nil]} [[1 3] [nil nil] [2 nil]])
=> [[1 3] [2 nil]]
```

---

I've just noticed that this answer is essentially the same as [Denis Fuenzola's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65056008/1562315), except that this one converts the answer back to a vector.